# Is this due to insufficient virtual memory that the java program cannot run?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, virtual-memory, virtual-member-manager

[image]
As shown in the figure, Windows displays that my physical machine has enough memory, including mem reduct showing that physical memory is sufficient. However, the virtual machine's memory has been consistently high, which caused an error when running the program. The error message is as follows, indicating that the JVM heap memory is insufficient.

`Unable to allocate 130176KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 4165632KB heap.`

My question is, when the physical memory is sufficient, why isn't the heap memory allocated for the program or the so-called `parallel garbage collection` allocated physical memory? It seems like it is allocating virtual memory.

Then, in my case, there were indeed a large number of programs running in the background, and the RAM of the entire machine was 16G. When I closed some applications, the virtual memory usage also decreased, and I was able to run the program normally. By the way, I also want to ask, when I have many programs running, are there any methods to reduce the computer's virtual memory usage?

I couldn't find any information saying that JVM heap memory is only allocated in virtual memory. In fact, it definitely occupies physical memory, so I am confused.

Comment: 'Virtual memory' does not mean 'disk'. All programs in Windows execute in 'virtual memory'.  Some of that virtual memory is mapped to physical memory; the mapping can change dynamically.

Comment: You should probably read up about virtual memory. Almost nothing allocates directly in physical memory. The requests for allocation go to virtual memory, and a part (or all) of virtual memory is mapped to physical memory at any time.